# Get Latest environment varibles for web app update

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, refresh, page-refresh, hot-reload

I implement a feature for my web app to when new version is deployed, show notification. For that i need to hard refresh same as "ctrl+f5" to get latest environment varibles.How I do it?

I need a way to implement hard refresh. now, location.reload(true) is not valid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.